# Empty text file being created instead of a sqlite database

Tags: flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

While creating my database using flask, when I'm doing `db.create_all()`, instead of being formed a database file a plain text empty file is being formed. I am using flask, with sqlalchemy orm and sqlite3 as database. My init.py file contains this...

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'main.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

from main import route
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'main.sqlite')
```

to

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'main.db')
```